# PHP Mailer not working on Go Daddy server despite it used to work?

Tags: php, html, server, phpmailer

I've setup a online quote builder on my website, essentially a large form that uses PHP Mailer to send the data to my email for me to read.

The code used to work on the server just fine using PHP Mailer but for some reason returns an error within the $errors[] as noted further down in the code snippet is what is being outputted. I would really appreciate some advice as I have tried many things including changing port numbers etc... The form posts to my send-quote.php page and the code for this is:

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    require_once 'inc/libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


    $errors = [];

    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['company'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['number'], $_POST['message'])) {

      $fields =  [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'company' => $_POST['company'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'],
        'message' => $_POST['message']
      ];

      foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
        if(empty($data)) {
          $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
        }
      }

      if(empty($errors)) {

        $m = new PHPMailer;

        $m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth = true;

        $m->Host = 'smtpout.europe.secureserver.net';
        $m->Username = 'my email goes here';
        $m->Password = 'my password goes here';
        $m->Port = 80;

        $m->isHTML();

        $m->Subject = 'Galaxy Radio Quote Builder';

        // Radio Advert type set

        $adverttype = "";
        if(isset($_POST['adverttype'])){
           $adverttype = $_POST['adverttype'];
        }

        // Advert features set

        $featureone = "";
        if(isset($_POST['featureone'])){
           $featureone = $_POST['featureone'];
        }
        $featuretwo = "";
        if(isset($_POST['featuretwo'])){
           $featuretwo = $_POST['featuretwo'];
        }
        $featurethree = "";
        if(isset($_POST['featurethree'])){
           $featurethree = $_POST['featurethree'];
        }

        // Additional services set

        $serviceone = "";
        if(isset($_POST['serviceone'])){
           $serviceone = $_POST['serviceone'];
        }
        $servicetwo = "";
        if(isset($_POST['servicetwo'])){
           $servicetwo = $_POST['servicetwo'];
        }
        $servicethree = "";
        if(isset($_POST['featurethree'])){
           $servicethree = $_POST['servicethree'];
        }

        // Advert duration set

        $advertduration = "";
        if(isset($_POST['advertduration'])){
           $advertduration = $_POST['advertduration'];
        }


        $m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' ' . $fields['company'] . ' ' . $fields['number'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p> ' . $adverttype . ' <br> ' . $featureone . ' <br> ' . $featuretwo . ' <br> ' . $featurethree . ' <br> ' . $serviceone . ' <br> ' . $servicetwo . ' <br> ' . $servicethree . ' <br> ' . $advertduration;

        $m->FromName = 'Galaxy Radio Website';

        $m->AddAddress('contact@galaxyradio.org', 'Galaxy Radio');

        if($m->send()) {
          header('Location: thanks.php');
          die();
        } else {
          $errors[] = "Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.";
        }

      }

    } else {
      $errors[] = "Something went wrong";
    }

    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    $_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

    header('Location: advertise-with-us.php');
```

When I try submitting the form on the advertise page, the error pops up that says: **Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.**

Any suggestions as to why the error comes up instead of actually sending. The code you see - DID WORK but NOW doesn't?? I have't changed anything

This is the error that I'm getting using the debug mode:

```
2016-09-04 20:59:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 n1plsmtpa01-03.prod.ams1.secureserver.net :SMTPAUTH: ESMTP 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.galaxyradio.org 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-n1plsmtpa01-03.prod.ams1.secureserver.net hello [46.252.205.133], secureserver.net 250-HELP 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN 250-SIZE 30000000 250-PIPELINING 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250 OK 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 454 TLS not available due to temporary reason 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 454 TLS not available due to temporary reason 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 n1plsmtpa01-03.prod.ams1.secureserver.net :SMTPAUTH: closing connection 
2016-09-04 20:59:40 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: Read the error messages that PHPMailer will put into `ErrorInfo`, like the PHPMailer example code does. You can also set `SMTPDebug = 2` and disable your redirects to allow you to see the output. GoDaddy is well known for blocking outound SMTP, as covered in the PHPMailer docs.

Comment: Where will the errors get outputted?? I get a blank screen

Comment: I've added the error below that I'm getting

Comment: So reading your debug output, TLS isn't working.  Try port 465 and SSL perhaps as a temporary fix.  There was another GoDaddy PhpMailer problem posted very recently.  Have you tried their forums or support?

Comment: This is still not working on the server?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with similar situations with GD, there are 2 things that tend to be the/a problem.

In many cases it doesnt even make sense for the fix to work but does indeed work.

1) They upgrade php and your version was switched and code becomes depreciated. They only show the last 3 releases as usable options. (try to switch php version to lower one)

2) This one is by going to the Cpanel, select MX records and then the domain name (if more than one record in Cpanel) and select remote mail handler.

I can not tell you how many people suffer email issues through CPanel and people are unaware of number 2. Not even employees.

Either way good luck.